# Undefined index when I remove extension php with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, xampp

I have this **.htaccess** code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /%1 [R=302,L]  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

and it seems to work correctly, but when I try to pass data with POST method:

**Notice**: Undefined index: email in **/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/project/login_form.php** on line 4

**Notice**: Undefined index: password in **/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/project/login_form.php** on line 5

Comment: To what URL are you making the request?

Comment: When you use this code `<?php print_r($_POST); ?>` So your POST array is empty...?

Comment: @juan Array ( )

Comment: @MrWhite form_login.php

Comment: @joisberg: Change `R=302` to `R=307` in your first rule to preserve POST data

Comment: "Change `R=302` to `R=307` in your first rule to preserve POST data" - But the URL you are submitting the POST data to should not be subject to a redirect in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I fix it!
I replace this

```
 <form action="login_form.php" method="POST">
```

to this

```
 <form action="login_form" method="POST">
```

Comment: Hopefully this helps you understand/remember that htaccess doesn't _remove_ anything, it is your responsibility as the developer to not include it in the first place. This causes htaccess to (effectively) 404 and that's why you need the rule.